# Can I get audio output from 2 DAW or music VST simultaneously with 1 keyboard input?

Tags: software, keyboard, fl-studio, pc

I have opened 2 music applications in my desktop:

1. a MIDI music studio without support for VST mode 
   (of course if it was supported I can easily run it from FL Studio!)
2. a DAW, FL Studio

Can I use a keyboard in both apps and get audio output from both applications at the same time and simultaneously?

Comment: Try it out and see? At least on the Mac it's possible, IIRC, to have multiple applications listen to the same MIDI input port simultaneously.

Comment: It probably depends on the MIDI interface drivers or MIDI-over-USB drivers. I can play my Novation MIDI controller and receive MIDI in several Windows applications at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing you are looking for is ReWire, the Propellerheads protocol to send audio from app to another application ( ReWire Client -> ReWire Host ).  Low Latency audio in windows means exclusive audio ( 1 application at a time sending stuff to the sound card ).  So you would have to see if your "Midi Studio without Support for VST mode" ( Reason?) supports ReWire.  of course if all you want to do is play 2 VSTs at the same time, almost any DAW can do this, just set the midi inputs on two separate tracks to the same channel, and arm both of them for recording.  Also there are plugins that host plugins ( AKAI VIP, Wusik X42 ) so you could accomplish that in that manner as well.  If you update your question with some specifics I could answer much better.